# Matlab saving cell array to text file

Tags: arrays, matlab, save, printf

After searching mathworks' website and here too I managed to find the code that is SUPPOSED to work for saving cell data to a text file... but every variation I found doesn't work. Here's my current code (and the one that has appeared the most here and on mathworks) - please help me figure out why it's not working for me...:

**first attempt:**

```
array = cell(1,10);
for i=1:10
    array{i} = 'someText';
end
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', array);
fclose(fid);
```

**Error:**

Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in saveToFile (line 11)
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', array);

So I specifically looked for one that is good for cell-arrays (can be found here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/write-to-delimited-data-files.html)

**Second attempt:**

```
array = cell(1,10);
for i=1:10
    array{i} = 'someText';
end
fileID = fopen('celldata.dat','w');
[nrows,ncols] = size(array);
for row = 1:nrows
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n' ,array{row,:});
end
fclose(fileID);
```

**Error:**

Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

Error in saveToFile (line 12)
fprintf(fileID,'%s\n' ,array{row,:});

I will spare you some other failed attempts.. these were the best I could find.. Any help will be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: I copied your second attempt into the command window in MATLAB and it worked perfectly!

Comment: You might want to use 'array{:}' instead of 'array' in your 1st attempt

Comment: Yes, if you do as Benoit suggests, the first approach works too =)

Comment: Have you checked which version you are using?

Comment: Ahhh - I have discovered the problem is with some of the string data I am using which appears as [] (matlab shows 'ans = []' in several places, where normally there's a string 'ans = 'someString') so I guess I need to replace [] with a string somehow.

Comment: Best replacement might be `''` and for checking `[]` use `isempty`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below works for me fine:

```
array = cell(10,1);
for i=1:10
  array{i} = ['someText ' num2str(i)];
end
fileID = fopen('celldata.dat','w');
[nrows,ncols] = size(array);
for row = 1:nrows
    temp_str = array{row,:};
    fprintf(fileID ,'%s\n', temp_str);
end
fclose(fileID);
```

the main difference is by assigning the cell content in a variable of type CHAR.

Comment: A bit delayed, but I'll update anyway to save others time - the second attempt I posted really did work, the thing is some of my (very large data) had 'NaN' as values, so once I discovered those and got rid of them it worked. Thank you all for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could use `strjoin` to join a cell array into a string:

```
array = cell(1,10);
for i=1:10
    array{i} = 'someText';
end
line = strjoin(array)
fid = fopen('file.txt', 'wt');
fprintf(fid, '%s\n', line);
fclose(fid);
```