# printing the content of a cell in matlab into a file

Tags: matlab

I have a cell datastructure and I am trying to print it to a file I keep getting this error :
 Error using fprintf
Function is not defined for 'cell' inputs.

```
solWT = optimizeCbModel(recon1,'max','one');
fileID = fopen('Q3.txt','w');
grRateWT = solWT.f
C=cell(2,2);
for system = 1:2%length(recon1.subSystems)
    system

    fluxReactions = recon1.rxns(ismember(recon1.subSystems,recon1.subSystems(system)));
    for reaction = 1:length(fluxReactions)
        model =  recon1;
        model.lb(reaction) = 0;
        model.ub(reaction) = 0;

    end
    solKO = optimizeCbModel(model,'max');
    C{system, 1} =  recon1.subSystems(system);
    C{system, 2} = solKO.f / grRateWT;
end
sortedCellArray = sortrows(C,2);
formatSpec = '%s %2.1f\n';
[nrows,ncols] = size(C);
for row = 1:nrows
    fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,sortedCellArray{row,:});
end
```

What am I doing wrong

Comment: Please provide a full executable example with example data.

Comment: @thewaywewalk Done

Comment: no, `recon1` is missing. We just need the content of variable `C` to help you, please think about some simple code to reproduce the structure of `C` - the actual numbers do not matter for this question, just the structure.

Comment: i think some element of C are cell arrays , for example c=cell(2,2); d=cell(1,1); d={5}; c(1)=d; then if you use fprintf(c{1}) it get that error

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26125280/matlab-saving-cell-array-to-text-file?rq=1

Comment: `fprintf` only takes text strings and `cell` is not a text string. What exactly do you want, a text file that merely tells the cell content *in human language*, or something to save the data structure so that you can use the cell in Matlab again?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
fprintf(fileID,formatSpec,sortedCellArray{row,1}, sortedCellArray{row,2})
```